# Analyze and get code/string of a jar file - Java

Tags: java, string, jar, contains, analyzer

I want to analyze the code (or strings) of a jar file (example: if a jar file contains "cheese"), I searched a lot but I don't know how to do this :/
I don't want to use JD-GUI because my program have to be automatic (user press a button and then he have to know if a jar file contains a specific method (for example "public void onEnable()" or a string (for example "cheese"))

I searched and I found:

[analyze jar file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314541/analyze-jar-file-programmatically)

[Extract source code from .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file)

https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-javaparser-analyzing-java-code-programmatically/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

[How to search for a string in JAR files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331025/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-jar-files)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of a duplicate .  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463192/reading-content-of-a-jar-file-at-runtime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

- open the jar with a [JarInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html)
- for each JarEntry do a *Class.forName* to load the class (compose the package correctly)
- use reflection to get the method names ([Class.getMethods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--))
- add the names, and required attributes, to a List to do the searches. Unless you are using huge jars or very old hardware you can do a simple full scan of the list of names using a contains() or [matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-), probably you do not need fancy indexing tools (Sphinx, Lucene, etc.).
  If the RegExp part should be slow, create a regexp [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) instance and reuse it.

A quick (Linux) alternative, for classes names only, is this:

jar tvf file.jar | grep ClassName

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfectly ! <3 And, last question: How can I get all jar files in a folder (for example "C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions") and to analyze them ? :)

Comment: File.listFiles(...) is the method you are looking for. If you want to include subdirectories too look at Apache commons.io FileUtils.iterateFilesAndDirs